# template navigation using Grails controllers

Tags: grails, controller

I am new to Grails and I am trying to get a template navigation bar to be populated dynamically through a controller.  I am really close to solving this but seem to have run into a wall lately.

I currently am getting the navigation to populate **only** when I click on the link for that controller.  Every where else the navigation just populates the bullet points for the links.  I am probably not referencing the controller correctly in my template but have not found any good examples yet.

using Grails 2.3.3
the controllers are dynamic.

Here is the code for my navigation template

```html
<body>
  
  <!-- Links to the committees go here -->
 <div class="leftMenu">  

  <!-- template of hospitals and there committees goes here -->  
 <div>
  <g:render template="/hospital/committeeTemp" />
 </div>

   <tr valign="top">
  <td> 
   <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">
   <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.events.gif" border="0">
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr valign="top">
  <td> 
   <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">
   <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.news.gif" border="0">
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr valign="top">
  <td> 
   <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">
   <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.help.gif" border="0">
   </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
<%--  </table>--%>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am using a nested loop to populate the navigation bar.  That code can be found here  [Grails navigation links nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353610/grails-navigation-links-nested-loop)

Comment: <g:link> translates to an <a href="" /> tag, which is why you're only getting the navigation to populate when you click the link. Since I don't know the rest of your code, all I can advise is, have you tried passing the values to the page (via the controller or whatnot) and processing it there?

Comment: I have updated my question with my code.

Comment: I guess I didn't phrase my question correctly.  What I am trying to do is have a navigation bar be populated dynamically throughout the scope of the site so that I can use these links like search filters for the main content.  I created a template to produce the correct format for the navigation links and I am rendering the template on the main.gsp page.  Yet the navigation bar only populates when I got to view that controller.

Answer (score 0):

With a little more knowledge under my belt.  I found out that it was only populating on that one page because that is where it was accessing that particular controller's action. So I ended up putting that mapping into ever action in my controller.