# Grails navigation links nested loop

Tags: grails, one-to-many

I have created a nested loop using Grails tags but not getting the output that I am expecting.  I am expecting a list of links nested within another set of links.  I am close but the nested links are being displayed as one big list, not multiple links.

I have two domains with a one-to-many relationship. My controller is currently dynamic.

writen in Grails 2.3.3

Here are my two domains

```
class Committees {

    String committeeName
    String description

    static belongsTo = [hospital:Hospital]

    static constraints = {
        committeeName (nullable:true)
        description( inList: ["Committee","Board"])
    }
}

class Hospital {
    String hospitalName

    static hasMany = [committees:Committees]

    static constraints = {
        hospitalName nullable:true
    }
}
```

Here is the nested loop in my .GSP

```
<g:each in="${hospitalInstanceList}" status="i" var="hospitalInstance">
<tr>
    <td>
        <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: hospitalInstance, field: "hospitalName")}</g:link>
        <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">
            <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">
                <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.msh_board.gif" border="0">
            </a>
        </g:link>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <g:each in="${hospitalInstance.id}" status="j" var="committeesInstance">
            <p>Current id: ${hospitalInstance.id }</p>
            <li>
<%--            <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance}">${fieldValue(bean: hospitalInstance, field: "committees.committeeName")}</g:link>--%>
                <g:link controller="Committees" action="show" id="${committeesInstanceList}">${fieldValue(bean: committeesInstance, field: "committeeName")}</g:link>
            </li>
            </g:each>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `${hospitalInstance.committees}` in inner loop.
Try this code

```html
<table border="1">
<g:each in="${hospitalInstanceList}" status="i" var="hospitalInstance">
                      <tr>
                          <td>
       
          <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">${hospitalInstance.hospitalName}</g:link>

          <g:link action="show" id="${hospitalInstance.id}">
          <a href="index.jsp?nav=main&hosp=<%=hospGiven %>" target="_top">
          <img src="/Trustees/static/images/img/navigate.msh_board.gif" border="0">
          </a>
          </g:link>

                          </td>
                      </tr>    

      <tr>     
                   <td>
                              <ul>
                   <g:each in="${hospitalInstance.committees}">
                                        <li>   <g:link action="show" id="${it.id}">  ${it.committeeName} </g:link> </li> 

                                         <br> 
                                        
                                        <li>  <g:link action="show" id="${it.id}">  ${it.description}</g:link> </li>
                                         
                                         
                                     </g:each>
                                               </ul>
                   </td>          
      </tr>
</g:each>    
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped out so much.  I was stuck on that for hours.

Comment: I know that this is after the fact, but I was wondering if you could explain why this code change worked.  Just hoping to learn something new.

Comment: @Daniel See ,  in your code , You did the second loop like  `<g:each in="${hospitalInstance.id}"` .  Now look at your Domain class Hospital , One Hospital has only one `id` . if you use `id` as counting variable in loop ,  loop will execute only once.. But what you really need is , You have to print all committees belong to a Hospital right? So ,  for a particular hospital Object , there are one or more committee instances associated , so you should set it as the looping construct..  So , if a hospital has 3 committees , `<g:each>` will iterate 3.. Is it clear now?

Comment: So in my code , `<g:each in="${hospitalInstance.committees}">` is the looping construct , which belongs to the set of committees associated with currently selected Hospital instance. If the current hospital has 3 committees , loop will execute 3 times , if it has 10 committees loop will go 10 times.. In each iteration `${ it }` belongs to current committee. Thats why I'm printing `${it.committeeName}` and  `${it.description}`